Could the presence of multiple stabilizer oxides induce sluggish diffusion in a stabilized zirconia to increase lifetime?
The presence of yttria stabilizes zirconia's high temperature allotropes, but it also decreases the lifetime due to more defects that can induce more diffusion into yttria rich and poor regions, reducing lifetime of the material. If one can reduce the diffusion of zirconia, one can reduce the cost, which lead to the next section.
There has also has been research on high entropy materials, including alloys, intermetallics and ceramics, in which the variance of radii distorts the lattice and inducing sluggish diffusion. However, only carbides and nitrides have been more researched while I could not find much research on fluorite structured oxides, which has the same or similar crystal structure as cubic zirconia.
Putting two and two together, if multiple stabilizer components oxides can be incorporated into zirconia, would the high entropy effects induce sluggish diffusion?

Using the prefix "-ia" for element oxides is unusual, sometimes very much. (zirconia = $\ce{ZrO2}$, yttria = $\ce{Y2O3}$, calcia= $\ce{CaO}$. I might have heard zirconia, but definitely not calcia.)

I think it is a material science/pottery shorthand

I have thought it might be the case

The fraction of zirconia's high temperature allotropes' structural features in such a high positional entropy material must be reduced just because of randomness. I don't think the resulting material is justified to be called "cubic zirconia", if its structure is that distorted.
Sluggish diffusion will probably happen.

one would probably limit the amount of stabilizer oxides to about less than 30 at% or even under 20 at%

In this case, there are no properties typical of high entropy alloys/materials.

then probably a mixture of early transition metal, alkaline earth metal, and lanthanide oxides would suffice that requirement

there is this article that may help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0955221918302115 composition HEFO5A looks like the least expensive one.
